# How to create a formula to calculate the different combinations of money amount distribution?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, binomial-coefficients

Let's say that you have an amount of 100 euros and you want to distribute all of it between 3 persons without taking into consideration the decimal fractions of the euro.

If we started with some simple scenarios, then we could say:

If instead of 3 we had just one person and since we have to distribute all of the amount then we would have just a single case.

If we had 2 persons then, I guess, that we would have 100 different combinations, of distribution among the persons.

For let's say 3 persons, I have tried to solve it with Binomial coefficient, since we are talking only about integers, like this:

```
C(n,r) = C(100,3) = (100!)/(3!(100−3)!) = 161.700
```

But the result seems pretty high and I guess that this is probably because this formula takes into consideration that every n is different, or something like that.

However, in a problem where n is currency unit and there is also the rule of distributing all of the amount, which means that we want to exclude the combinations like
1€-1€-1€,
1€-1€-2€,
... then to be honest, I do not know how to approach this problem to create a formula, so any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Google "stars and bars."

Comment: @saulspatz Doesn't "stars and bars" lead to a binomial coefficient? Which again is solved using nCr ?

Comment: Yes, of course.  I was responding to the last line, which I take to be the question.

Comment: Are you assuming that each person receives at least some of the money?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I would like to be able to calculate both of the cases. For example to be able to determine the minimum amount of each person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let "o" represent $1$ Euro and let "|" represent divisor. It is obvious that we need $2$ divisors and applying repeated permutation into "ooo...o||"  ($100$ "o" and $2$ divisors) gives us $\binom{102}{2}=5151$ different distribution.  $$\\$$
For example, "ooo...o|ooo...|ooo" ($51$ "o" on left, $46$ "o" on middle, $3$ "o" on right) is $51$ Euro for $1^{st}$ person, $46$ Euro for $2^{nd}$ person and $3$ Euro for $3^{rd}$ person.

Comment: great! thanks for the example using stars and bars but how does the binomial coefficient is configured when you need to make sure that in every combination each person gets an X minimum value? Because the default binomial coefficient I think that also include the scenarios where each person gets zero (euros or "O"s)

Comment: If each person gets X minimum value, then the result will be $\binom{102-3x}{2}$ (first give each one in X amount, then use stars and bars)